# Registering mIRC for domain users

Tags: license, windows-domain, mirc

We run a small domain with mIRC installed on the machines.
When we install mIRC we do so with the local administrator account. We register it and it shows as registered fine.

However when another user logs on it shows mIRC as not registered. Has anyone run into this before, if so how did you solve it?

I have also tried registering it with a domain admins account but the same thing happens.

Comment: I would send an email to the company behind mIRC.  My guess is that the license file is incorrectly connected to the user which installed.  I say that it behavior is only incorrect because it would make more sense to put the Application Data so an user could acess it.  Copy the license file or simply register it again.

Comment: I've e-mailed him but was hoping someone had found a workaround. Registering it for every user who uses those machines is a no-no unfortunately (thankfully)

Comment: Do you have enough licenses?

Comment: @ramhound - Yes, 1 per machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this reply from mIRC. This solves the problem.

Hello Joseph,

Sorry for the late reply.

If you register mIRC under the administrator account, the registration will be stored in the administrators current user (HKCU) location in the Windows registry, so it won't work with anyone else who logs into the machine.

However, mIRC does check to see if a registration has been stored in the Local Machine (HKLM) location. You would need to copy over the "mIRC"
section from the HKCU registry location:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\mIRC

to the HKLM registry location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\mIRC

(I have attached an example file that you need to fill in with your
details)

Now when you run mIRC from any account, it should see the registration.

Does that resolve the issue for you?

Regards,

Khaled Mardam-Bey
mIRC Co. Ltd.